# Sharedpreferences remove not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

Hope someone could help, dealing with this for 3 days straight not luck, losing my hair!!.
I am able to save and load back the objects from the shared preferences but I can't not remove them, it does not work. I get no errors

It loads from and add objects to the sharedpreferences normally, but when I call the remove method it reloads the arrays list and pulls a new array of objects different from the original load losing the position. Not sure if makes sense; hope someone could help.

```
public class FavFragment extends Fragment {
Context context;
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<VocabCatModel> vocabCatList;
FavVocabAdapter adapter;
SharedPreference sharedPreference;

public static FavFragment newInstance() {
    FavFragment fragment = new FavFragment();
    return fragment;
}

public FavFragment() {
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPreference=new SharedPreference(getActivity());
    System.out.println("Loading Favorites new SHaredpreference object");
    try {
        vocabCatList = sharedPreference.loadFavorites(getActivity());
        System.out.println("Current Favs: " + vocabCatList);
        System.out.println("Current context after loading first time:" + getActivity());
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vocab_search, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("onResume", "onResume Called");
    if(vocabCatList != null ) {
        try {
            Log.e("adapter", "new adapter and setting up to listview");
            adapter = new FavVocabAdapter(getActivity(), vocabCatList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            System.out.println("Favs after lv.setadapter: "+ vocabCatList);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3){
            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(getActivity(), vocabCatList.get(position));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), vocabCatList.get(position) + "removed",              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            vocabCatList.remove(vocabCatList.get(position));
            return true;
        }
    });
}


public class FavVocabAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<VocabCatModel> vocabCatList;
    public FavVocabAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VocabCatModel> vocabCatList){
        this.context = context;
        this.vocabCatList = vocabCatList;
    }
    public int getCount(){return vocabCatList.size();}
    public Object getItem(int position){return vocabCatList.get(position);}
    public long getItemId(int position){return position;}

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName,tvTranslation;
        ImageView ivImage;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        final ViewHolder holder;
        //convertView = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.categorylistviewitem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
            holder.tvTranslation = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.translationTextView);
            holder.ivImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvName.setText(vocabCatList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvTranslation.setText(vocabCatList.get(position).getTranslation());
        holder.ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
        holder.ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(context, vocabCatList.get(position));
                    vocabCatList.remove(vocabCatList.get(position));
                    holder.ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.directions);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}

}
```

////////////////////////Shared preference class I am using

```
public class SharedPreference {
private Context context;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "VOCAB_APP";
public static final String FAVORITES = "Favorite";

public  SharedPreference(Context context){

  super();
}


public void storeFavorites(Context context, List<VocabCatModel> favorites){
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
    System.out.println(favorites);

    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

    System.out.println("commit()");
    editor.apply();


}
public ArrayList<VocabCatModel> loadFavorites(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<VocabCatModel> favorites;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println("loading favorites");
        VocabCatModel[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,VocabCatModel[].class);
        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList<>(favorites);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<VocabCatModel>) favorites;
}
public void addFavorite(Context context, VocabCatModel vocabCatModel) {
    List<VocabCatModel> favorites = loadFavorites(context);
    if (favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    favorites.add(vocabCatModel);
    storeFavorites(context, favorites);
}

public void removeFavorite(Context context, VocabCatModel vocabCatModel) {
    ArrayList<VocabCatModel> favorites = loadFavorites(context);
    System.out.println("Removing favorite");
    System.out.println("new favs" + favorites);
    if (favorites != null) {
        System.out.println("object from click" + vocabCatModel);
        favorites.remove(vocabCatModel);
        System.out.println(context);
        storeFavorites(context, favorites);

    }
   }

}
```

Comment: Are you hitting your System print calls as you would expect?

Comment: there is very little chance that `favorites.remove(vocabCatModel);` actually works. test the return value.

Comment: @zgc7009 Yes I am hitting the System print calls as expected..

Answer (score 0):

if you need to delete or remove the object or the item you put before
try this:

```
SharedPreferences settings;
Editor editor;
settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = settings.edit();
try{
    System.out.println("PREFS_NAME:"+settings.getString(PREFS_NAME,""));
    editor.remove(PREFS_NAME);
    editor.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Cart Error");
}
```

i think this will delete object from sharedprederences